# Python variable names __ and _ and @property syntax with declaration location

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm a bit confused here as to a few things.

1. when and how we should variable names that begin with a single underscore `_` and a double underscore `__` be used.
2. when should the `@property` tag be used
3. When should variables be declared outside of the init method vs. when should they be declared inside of it?

Below is a code sample to show an example usage (which may be incorrectly used).

```
class GenClass(object):
    _variable1 = None
    __variable2 = None

    @property
    variable3 = None

    def __init__(self, v4):
        self.variable4 = v4
```

**What is the difference between all these?** They seem implicit and to the naked eye could be seen as the same, but I've been beginning to notice they are all different.

Comment: You can't use `property` - or any decorator - on an attribute. It wraps a method.

Comment: `__`, `_` and `@property` are all the same thing really, in python there is no private and public, it's just to make to code more readable and indicate how certain properties of object should be called. Deciding when to feed arguments to your __init__ depends on your class. can you define the property from within the object then it is more efficient to do some most of the time, if you cannot you need to pass the property to the object upon instantiation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `_` and `__` at the start of a variable/property name indicate that the property is supposed to be "protected" or "private" respectively and should not be touched by code outside the same class/module. `__` triggers some actual light name mangling to really prevent name clashes with inheriting classes, but ultimately both are just conventions to hint the intended usage to programmers. Don't touch a `_` variable if it's not "yours", because the author makes no guarantees that this property will always be there and/or will always be useful.
2. `@property` should be used when you want to execute a method when a property is being accessed (instead of direct access to a plain property). This has several uses, including computed/virtual properties (values gets computed upon reading the property) and to force read-only properties:

   ```
   @property
   def foo(self):
       '''Can read, but can't write to .foo'''
       return 'bar'
   ```
3. Declaring a property *on the class* makes this property identical across all instances of the class. Declaring it on `self` makes it particular to that instance. *Usually* you want the latter.